# $U_n$ convergence and the value of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let
>   $$U_n=\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{\left( ...\left(\left(\left(\left(2-\frac1{4^n}\right)^2-2\right)^2-2\right)^2-2\right)^2...-2\right)^2}}$$
>   Show that $U_n$ is convergent and find its limit.

Intuitively, if the sequence converges, when $n$ becomes large the $\frac{1}{4^{n}}$ term vanishes so that $\left(2-\frac1{4^n}\right)^2$ tends to 4, resulting in $U_n$ converging to 4. But I cannot figure out a method to prove the convergence of the sequence or to find the limit value.

Comment: What is exactly is the process that you do $n$-times? $(Ans)^2-2$?

Comment: $U_n$ is increasing and the upper bound for $U_\infty$ with $U_n<U_\infty$ is $4-\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{4^k})\,$  (I have shown this below - I hope this is right. :-)). The lower bound is of course $U_1$.

Comment: @user90369 Your calculations are right!

Comment: @Wore : Thanks for checking it ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The limit is not equal to $4$. In fact, every element $U_n$ is bounded above by $\displaystyle{4-\prod_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^{k}}\right)}$.

Fixing $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the reals $r_n(n),r_n(n-1),\ldots,r_n(1)$ defined recursively (from $k=n$ to $k=1$) as follows:

$$\begin{cases}r_n(n)&=1-\dfrac{1}{4^{n+1}}\\ r_n(k-1)&=r_n(k)\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(k)}{4^k}\right)\end{cases}$$

> **Claim 1:** For every $k\leq n$ we have $0<r_n(k)<1$.

*Proof:* By recursion from $k=n$ to $k=1$, it is clear that $0<r_n(n)<1$. For the inductive case (from $k$ to $k-1$) we have:

\begin{align*}
0&<r_n(k)<1\\ 
0&>\dfrac{-r_n(k)}{4^k}>-\dfrac{1}{4^k}\\
1&>1-\dfrac{r_n(k)}{4^k}>1-\dfrac{1}{4^k}>0\\
\end{align*}
and so, $r_n(k-1)=r_n(k)\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(k)}{4^k}\right)$ satisfies $0<r_n(k-1)<1$ because it is the product of two elements between $0$ and $1$. $\Box$

Also, for a given $n$, we can consider the sequence defined recursively by:
$$\begin{cases}a_n(1)=\left(2-\dfrac{1}{4^n}\right)^2\\ a_n(k+1)= \left(a_n(k)-2\right)^2\end{cases}$$

*Notice that we have $U_n=a_n(n)$.*

> **Claim 2:** For $k\leq n$, $a_n(k)=4-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k}}$.

*Proof:* By induction on $k$. For $k=1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a_n(1)&=\left(2-\dfrac{1}{4^n}\right)^2=4-\dfrac{4}{4^n}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2n}}=4-\dfrac{1}{4^{n-1}}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=4-\dfrac{r_n(n)}{4^{n-1}}=4-\dfrac{r_n(n-1+1)}{4^{n-1}}\hspace{1cm}\checkmark
\end{align*}

Suppose the result for $k$, with $k<n$. Then we have:

\begin{align*}
a_n(k+1)&=(a_n(k)-2)^2=\left(\left(4-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k}}\right)-2\right)^2\\
&=\left(2-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k}}\right)^2\\
&=4-4\cdot\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k}}+ \dfrac{\left(r_n(n-k+1)\right)^2}{4^{2(n-k)}}\\
&=4-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k-1}}\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k+1}}\right)\\
&=4-\dfrac{1}{4^{n-k-1}}\left(r_n(n-k+1)\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(n-k+1)}{4^{n-k+1}}\right)\right)\\
&=4-\dfrac{1}{4^{n-k-1}}\cdot r_n(n-k)\\
&=4-\dfrac{r_n(n-(k+1)+1)}{4^{n-(k+1)}}\hspace{1cm}\checkmark\Box
\end{align*}

> **Proposition:** For every $n$, $U_n\leq \displaystyle{4-\prod_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^k}\right)}$

*Proof:* First, notice that by definition and Claim 1 we have:
$$0<r_n(k)<1 \Rightarrow 1-\dfrac{0}{4^k}=1>1-\dfrac{r_n(k)}{4^k}>1-\dfrac{1}{4^k}.$$

Therefore, by Claim 2,

\begin{align*}
U_n&=a_n(n)=4-\dfrac{r_n(n-n+1)}{4^{n-n}}=4-r_n(1)&\\
&=4-\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(2)}{4^2}\right)r_n(2)&\text{(by recursive definition of $r_n(1)$)}\\
&\leq 4-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^2}\right)\cdot r_n(2)&\text{(by the previous inequalities)}\\
&=4-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{r_n(3)}{4^3}\right)\cdot r_n(3) &\text{(by recursive definition of $r_n(2)$)}\\
&\leq 4-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^3}\right)\cdot r_n(3)\\
&\hspace{0.5cm}\vdots\hspace{2cm}\vdots \hspace{2cm}\vdots\\
&=4-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^3}\right)\cdots \left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^n}\right)r_n(n)\\
&=4-\prod_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^{k}}\right) &\Box
\end{align*}

---

$n$ steps

$(2-\frac{1}{4^n})^2=4-\frac{r_n}{4^{n-1}}$ with $r_n=1-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}$

$((2-\frac{1}{4^n})^2-2)^2=4-\frac{r_{n-1}}{4^{n-2}}$ with $r_{n-1}=r_n(1-\frac{r_n}{4^n})$

$(((2-\frac{1}{4^n})^2-2)^2-2)^2=4-\frac{r_{n-2}}{4^{n-3}}$ with $r_{n-2}=r_{n-1}(1-\frac{r_{n-1}}{4^{n-1}})$

...

$U_n=4-\frac{r_1}{4^0}$ with $r_1=r_2(1-\frac{r_2}{4^2})$

=>

$U_n=4-r_2(1-\frac{r_2}{4^2})\le 4-r_2(1-\frac{1}{4^2})$

$U_n\le 4-r_3(1-\frac{r_3}{4^3})(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\le 4-r_3(1-\frac{1}{4^3})(1-\frac{1}{4^2}) $

...

$U_n\le 4-(1-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{4^n}) (1-\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}) $...$(1-\frac{1}{4^2})$

$3<U_1=4-(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\le U_{\infty}\le 4-\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{4^k})\ll 4$

*Conclusion*:

$U_n$ is increasing and the upper bound is $4-\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{4^k})\,$ .